# Adding One with a number which has zeros in the begining

Tags: php

I have this variable `$value1= 000001;` which as you can see contains some numbers which begins with 0.

What I am trying to is add "1" with the variable so that when I echo it looks like this `000002`. Again for example if the variable is like this `$value1= 012001;` I want to make it look like `012002`.

I have tried like following but the result it produces is only "2"

```
$value1= 000001;  
echo $value+1;
```

Could you please show me how to achieve this?

thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways to do this, here's a different one:

```
$value1 = '000101';

$strLen = strlen($value1);
$value  = (((int) $value1) + 1);
echo str_pad($value, $strLen, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

php test.php 
000102

Answer (score 1):

Use printf

```
<?php 
$value1 = 2;
printf("%06d", 2);
```

Correction: number_format wouldn't be useful here, removed that.

Addendum: unless you're intending to work with octal numbers, don't start a numeric literal with a 0 as PHP interprets numbers starting with 0 as being octal.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with `str_pad`, as it's faster and, more importantly: more readable, than `printf` (`number_format` isn't relevant here). `echo str_pad($value+1, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code but its giving me wrong result, I tried this `$value1= 000001; echo str_pad($value1+1, 6, '0');` And the result I got is 200000. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$value1= 000001;
printf( "%06d", $value + 1 );
```

Comment: When `$value1= 000001;`I am getting the correct result (000002) but when  `$value1= 001001;` it is giving me wrong result(000514)

Comment: That's because octal 1001 is 513 in decimal, thus 513 + 1 = 514, That is to say, you assignments should not have the leading zeroes.  Makes PHP think you are giving it octal (base 8) numbers.)